# Windows Remote Desktop auto disconnection due to autologin

Tags: windows, rdp, remote, desktop

I am working with machine that are hosting several PCs running windows 7 pro.

I quite often need to connect to these PCs using windows remote desktop. This PCs need to have the autologin feature ON (session need to be localy open when the machine startup).

However I have discovered that when autologon is ON, for some reason remote desktop randomly close the session saying that an other user tries to connect. This is really easy to reproduce, as soon as you activate the autologin, you soon will get disconnected.

Any idea how to solve this issue (other than turnin off autologin) ?

Thanks in adance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually the ForceAutoLogon which gives problem (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon). The auto login at startup can stay ON and it gives no problem.

I can actually live without the ForceAutoLogon, so I should be fine ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with remote desktop, since connecting to the machine with remote desktop will log out the user on the console, and when it automatically logs in again, you get disconnected.

Use another technology such as VNC, which does not have this limitation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Sound still strange to me that this disconnection happens random. Sometime few seconds some time several minutes...